# How to do smooth screen rotation in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

How can I do smooth screen rotation in react-native with expo?

```
import * as ScreenOrientation from 'expo-screen-orientation';
 ScreenOrientation.lockAsync(ScreenOrientation.OrientationLock.LANDSCAPE_LEFT);
```

I'm using this code but it kind of breaks the screen in half when it spins and it looks horrible...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.